# How to write to a log file in a subdirectory using SLF4J and SimpleLogger (Windows)

Tags: java, path, slf4j

I am using SLF4J `SimpleLogger` in my Java application and I want to configure it to output to a file in a subdirectory called `log` of the current working directory.

```
E.g. <cwd>/log/log-file.log
```

I have configured it as follows:

```
System.setProperty(org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.LOG_FILE_KEY, "log/log-file.log");

// set other properties

log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.class);
```

On OS X this works as expected - i.e. a file called `log-file.log` is created in the directory `<cwd>/log`.

However, on Windows an exception is thrown when `getLogger` is called.

```
Could not open [log/log-file.log]. Defaulting to System.err
Reported exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log\log-file.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
    at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.computeTargetStream(SimpleLogger.java:219)
    at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.init(SimpleLogger.java:201)
    at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.<init>(SimpleLogger.java:262)
    at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleLoggerFactory.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:301)
```

If I set the property without specifying a subdirectory it works OK.

```
System.setProperty(org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.LOG_FILE_KEY, "log-file.log");
```

The Javadoc says that `logfile` property is "The output target which can be the *path* to a file".

How do I achieve the same behaviour on Windows as on OS X - i.e. write the log file to a subdirectory of the current working directory?

Comment: Just guessing... try to create the `log` sub dir manually on Windows.

Comment: "log/log-file.log" is not a windows path. You need to use the windows-notation on windows. Try to use [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)

Comment: `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("logs", "log-file.log").toString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem isn't really related to `SimpleLogger` but `FileOutputStream`. On Windows if the directory doesn't exist then it needs to be created first. This isn't necessary on OS X.

Comment: I would have expected the behavior to be the same on both platforms. Perhaps I'm naive.